# Flutter: How to add a column widget inside a bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

I've tried the following and got the out, but the body went blank.
Is there any way to add a column or a listview inside a bottom navigation bar

```
 Column(
    mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              //button1
         ),
          Expanded(
              //button2
               ),
          Expanded(
             //button3)
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            //button4
          ),
          Expanded(
            //button5)
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 25):

Apart from the issue posed by Expanded widget (as pointed out in [the answer by alexandreohara](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59004888/7902052)),
Column's `mainAxisSize` attribute is set to `MainAxisSize.max` by default. That means the column will try to occupy all the space available (the entire screen height).

Setting Column's `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min` will wrap the Column widget to occupy the least possible space(vertically) and not span the entire screen.

Following is the way it can be done:

```
    Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, 
        children: [...]
    );
```

Comment: You saved my ~day~ live ! Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Krasava ty je est

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem using a Column in a BottomNavigationBar. I think that your problem is wrapping everything in Expanded. It doesn't know the width of the widgets inside, and because of that, it will return blank.

Try to remove those Expanded widgets and try this:

```
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
   children: [FlatButton(...), FlatButton(...)],
)
```